# On page load show the value in textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, input

I am using asp.net mvc2.

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#candidatecontact").hide();              
          document.getElementById("counting").value =  '<%=ViewData["ResumesCount"] %>';
            $('#butt2').click(function () 
            {
                 count();
            });
        });    

function count() {               
             var tempId = <%=Model.Id%>; 
             var url = '/Page/Count';
             $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    data: { id : tempId}, 
                    dataType: "int",
                    success : function (count) {                            
                        SetCount(count);                            
                    }
                });                                     
        }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<% ViewData["ResumesCount"] = remainingHorsCount; %>
<input id = "counting" type = "text" style="width:20px;"/>
```

when page load in the above textbox show the value of `ViewData["ResumesCount"]`.. Please give me the ideas to do this?

Comment: Is this ASP or ASP.NET? Please add a tag to represent whatever is responsible for `<%...%>` here.

Comment: i am using asp.net mvc.. i want jquery only

Comment: what error your getting ?

Comment: when using jquery, then make the most of it, dont use raw javascript. change this `document.getElementById("counting").value =  '<%=ViewData["ResumesCount"] %>'` to ` $('#counting') .val(<%=ViewData["ResumesCount"] %>);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input id = "counting" type = "text" value="<%= remainingHorsCount%>" style="width:20px;"/>
```

or

```
<input id = "counting" type = "text" value="<%= ViewData['ResumesCount']%>" style="width:20px;"/>
```